# Clean way to identify color scheme in Python QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

When I do in the Python QGIS console `QgsColorSchemeRegistry.instance().schemes()`, it returns the following

```
[<qgis._core.QgsColorScheme object at 0x7f6cc5d8ccc8>,
 <qgis._core.QgsColorScheme object at 0x7f6cc5d8c938>,
 <qgis._core.QgsColorScheme object at 0x7f6cc5f54c30>]
```

If I loop the schemes with `[scheme.schemeName() for scheme in QgsColorSchemeRegistry.instance().schemes()]`, I get:

```
[u'Recent colors',
 u'Standard colors',
 u'Project colors']
```

So, it seems that all schemes have been through a cast so the only way to make the difference is via their `schemeName` but it's not generic when you use other languages.

In my understanding, I would expect a list with returned content like below:

```
[<qgis._core.QgsRecentColorScheme object at 0x7f6cc5d8ccc8>,
 <qgis._core.QgsGplColorScheme object at 0x7f6cc5d8c938>,
 <qgis._core.QgsProjectColorScheme object at 0x7f6cc5f54c30>]
```

First, my guess is right?

Secondly, what is the "best" way to manage this case properly, if any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems it was a bug in QGIS <= 2.12. Coincidentally I'd fixed it just a few days before your question (https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/de1001b9f78dedc511be1b5de594308efdf686de) .

So in QGIS > 2.12.1 this will behave correctly.

In response to your second question: "what is the "best" way to manage this case properly, if any?"

File a bug over at http://hub.qgis.org. It needs to be fixed in QGIS itself, so we'd very much like to know if you encounter situations like this.

Comment: if type are "right" like described, I think I can manage it by testing with `isinstance` without continuing to manage tests via the `schemeName()`. I don't think I should open a new bug, with your correction. I missed something?

Comment: No need to file a bug about this one, it's fixed now. I just meant if you encountered other cases where python objects aren't correctly downcast.

Comment: Just a ping about something related (impossibility to have a reference to a QWidgetAction with a deterministic approach) https://hub.qgis.org/issues/14011